# Memory Monitor in xCode 4 - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, android-activity, monitor

How can I monitor the memory used on my iPhone in xCode 4?

I need a tool like the Activity Monitor on previous versions of xCode. Or any other analysis tools?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Product -> Profile, and then the Instruments will be waken up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Toro, I am going to complete his answer for XCode 4.6:

First Enable profiler for your app

[image: Profile Menu]

Then Start Instruments tool

[image: Instruments Menu]